# library import in another project generates error with .net5

Tags: c#, .net-5, asp.net5

I have a library built in net5 in which I added through nuget Portable BouncyCastle (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.BouncyCastle/), it does not throw me any compilation error I can even use the classes of said library without any problem, the problem happens when I import my library into a web application also built in net5, here it throws me the following error

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load the file or assembly 'BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version = 1.9.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 0e99375e54769942 '. The system cannot find the specified file. I don't know if soon someone knows the cause of the error

this error happens to me with other libraries like Newtonsoft.Json, so I don't think it is the Portable BouncyCastle library

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You will need to provide more information.  How are you including BouncyCastle into your project (NuGet?).  What does the reference look like in the project (its properties)?  Is the assembly named correctly (full strong name) and in the right place?  How are you "importing" your assembly into the web application?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I am importing my library through project reference pointing to the dll generated by the library that contains the BouncyCastle import through NuGet

Answer (score 0):

You are using teamcity right? did you find any solution to this?

I am struggeling with the same thing,
but I got it to work locally by using dotnet cli

```
dotnet pack -c release -o C:\temp
```

Now I can see the dependencies within nuspec

**EDIT**

If you are using teamcity:

We had success with just migrating to .net 6

**OR**

Using .net pack instead of nuget pack:
Then you need to select the artifact paths in general settings for the respective build config.

```
Security\bin\Release\net5.0\Security-V2.1.0.1.nupkg
```

The version number as seen above has to be equal to what you have set in .csproj which is a bit cumbersome.

Don't use the version suffix which is suggested in the .net steps that will add a "dash and whatever" to version property in nuspec which is not allowed and the package will be invisible in Nuget manager.